# Get one row of grouped objects

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains a Husband to Wife realtion.
The table contains two rows for each realtion(BTW,gender has no meaning.it could be Husband-Husband and Wife-Wife. just saying). meaning, the table might show result of two rows for a "connection":
`Wife--Husband` and\or `Husband--Wife`
The table looks like this:

```
 Id1    | Id2  | ConnectiondID  |  RelatedConnectionId
 -----------------------------------------------------
 123    | 333  |    FF45        |        F421
 333    | 123  |    F421        |        FF45
 456    | 987  |    F333        |        F321
 987    | 456  |    F321        |        F333
```

My expected result is to have only one relation per group:

```
Id1  | Id2
----------
123  | 333
456  | 987
```

Comment: You have shown a bigamous relationship in your sample data.  Hence, I don't understand the question.

Comment: Shouldn't ID2 for the second row point to 123? If not, how do you determine which ID number to return in your expected result? To me the data implies that 123 is married to 333, who is married to 222 (And not 123).

Comment: sorry guys. data mistake

Comment: Does wanting `123|333` (and not `333|123`) mean you can just take the lower id as the primary one? Or some other rule to select the required pair?

Comment: yes. it doesn't matter which one of the rows since I have both's Id's stored in columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually very simple assuming you only want couples and your `ID` values are all unique and numeric, and does not require any self joins, functions or grouping:

```
declare @t table(Id1 int,Id2 int,ConnectiondID nvarchar(5),RelatedConnectionId nvarchar(5));
insert into @t values(123,333,'FF45','F421'),(333,123,'F421','FF45'),(456,444,'FF46','F422'),(444,456,'F422','FF46'),(789,555,'FF47','F423'),(555,789,'F423','FF47');

select *
from @t
where Id1 < Id2
order by Id1
```

Output:

```
+-----+-----+---------------+---------------------+
| Id1 | Id2 | ConnectiondID | RelatedConnectionId |
+-----+-----+---------------+---------------------+
| 123 | 333 | FF45          | F421                |
| 444 | 456 | F422          | FF46                |
| 555 | 789 | F423          | FF47                |
+-----+-----+---------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: what should I do in case one of the columns is nulls? should I use isnull() method?

Comment: @YanivEliav  That would depend on what your `null` values mean and where you would be seeing them.  For example, if you will always have a value in the `ID1` column, you can just add `or ID2 is null` to the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you need to perform a self-join on the table e.g. `ON t1.id1 = t2.id2` or `ON t1.ConnectionId = t2.RelatedConnectionID` and obviously this is joining both ways.

To limit this to just one way add a condition on the join predicate such that one of the values is less than or greater than the other; e.g.

```
DECLARE @tbl table( Id1 smallint PRIMARY KEY, Id2 smallint,ConnectiondID char(5),RelatedConnectionId char(5));
INSERT @tbl(Id1,Id2,ConnectiondID,RelatedConnectionId)
 VALUES(123,333,'FF45','F421'),
       (333,123,'F421','FF45'),
       (456,222,'FF45','F421'),
       (222,456,'F421','FF45'),
       (789,111,'FF45','F421'),
       (111,789,'F421','FF45');

SELECT * 
FROM @tbl t1
JOIN @tbl t2 ON t2.Id1 = t1.Id2 AND t2.Id1 > t1.Id1;
```

Comment: There is no need to use self join to work out whether one `ID` value is more or less than the other, per my answer below.

Comment: @iamdave - the self join is not to work out if one value is lower then the other, rather the less than/greater than predicate has been added to a join in order to filter down to single rows where a self-join is already necessary for any other reasons.

Comment: You are missing my point that the self join is not necessary.  All you need to check for here is a condition where one set of `ID` values is returned and not the other.  As they are both numeric, simply filtering for where one is less than the other returns the desired dataset.

Comment: @iamdave can I use the filtering when obne value ia higher than the other? in case of nulls and using isnull()?

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (id1 int, id2 int,ConnectiondID varchar(5),RelatedConnectionId varchar(5) )
 INSERT INTO @T (Id1,Id2,ConnectiondID,RelatedConnectionId)
 VALUES
 (123    , 333 ,'FF45','F421'),
 (333    , 123 , 'F421','FF45'),
 (2123    , 2333 ,'2FF45','2F421'),
 (2333    , 2123 , '2F421','2FF45'),
 (3    , 2 , 'AAAA','BBB'),
 (2    , 3 , 'BBB','AAAA')

SELECT  
    a.*
FROM 
    @t a
WHERE 
    CASE 
    WHEN ConnectiondID > RelatedConnectionId
    THEN RelatedConnectionId
    ELSE NULL 
    END IS NULL
```

Comment: Why do you have a `case` expression in your `where`?  Why not just do `where ConnectiondID > RelatedConnectionId` ?

Comment: You right,  ConnectiondID > RelatedConnectionId OR RelatedConnectionId IS NULL